# Как увеличить размер ссылки на n-ое кол-во пикселей от 100% CSS

Tags: html

У меня возникла проблема, я хочу сделать меню с ссылками, но их ширина выставляется не по ширине ячеек, а по ширине текста (точнее не учитывается padding). В итоге кликабельно, но не по всей ширине.

```
    menu li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px 25px;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 -2px;
        border-right: solid 2px #909090;
    }
    menu li a {
        display: inline-block;
        height: inherit;
        width: 100%;
        color: #909090;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Пробовал переставлять padding и border на сами ссылки, но тогда все съезжает.
[image: пиксели]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  border-right: solid 2px #909090;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #909090;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Там в таком случае крайняя правая ссылка еще имеет "вылет" на пикселей 50 вправо. У меня с этим проблема, потому что, я пробовал padding переставлять, но там такой артефакт возникает

Comment: Оно нажимается где надо, но еще и где не надо) https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpGvG.png

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `padding` у `menu li` и добавьте его в `menu li a`.

```css
menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  border-right: solid 2px #909090;
}

menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  color: #909090;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </li>
</menu>
```